# Fix the order of strings that have both letter and number components

Tags: r

I have string data like below.

```
a <- c("53H", "H26","14M","M47")
##"53H" "H26" "14M" "M47"
```

I want to fix the numbers and letters in a certain order such that
the numbers goes first, the letters goes second, or the other way around.
How can I do it?

```
##"53H" "26H" "14M" "47M"
```

or

```
##"H53" "H26" "M14" "M47"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can extract the numbers and letters separately with `gsub`, then use `paste0`
to put them in any order you like.

```
a <- c("53H", "H26","14M","M47")
( nums <- gsub("[^0-9]", "", a) )    ## extract numbers
# [1] "53" "26" "14" "47"
( lets <- gsub("[^A-Z]", "", a) )    ## extract letters
# [1] "H" "H" "M" "M"
```

**Numbers first answer**:

```
paste0(nums, lets)
# [1] "53H" "26H" "14M" "47M"
```

**Letters first answer**:

```
paste0(lets, nums)
# [1] "H53" "H26" "M14" "M47"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can capture the relevant parts in groups using `()` and then backreference them using `gsub`:

```
a <- c("53H", "H26","14M","M47")

gsub("^([0-9]+)([A-Z]+)$", "\\2\\1", a)
# [1] "H53" "H26" "M14" "M47"
```

This is like saying "Find a group of numbers at the start of my string and capture them in a group (`^([0-9]+)`). Then find the group of letters that go on to the end of my string and capture them in a second group (`([A-Z]+)`). That's my search pattern. Next, replace it such that the second group (referred to by `\\2`) is returned first and the first group (referred to by `\\1`) is returned second).

Comment: Thank you for the response. But if I try to order the number first, letter second, using the code >> gsub("^([0-9]+)([A-Z]+)$", "\\1\\2", a), it returned exactly the same order as orginal >>[1] "53H" "H26" "14M" "M47". But if I reverse your searching pattern but not the ordering pattern >> gsub("^([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)$", "\\2\\1", a), it will give me the correct return. I wonder why is that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From Ananda Mahto's answer, you can order the number first and letter second using the following code:

```
gsub("^([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)$", "\\2\\1", a)
```

because you want to capture the strings which start with a letter (`^([A-Z]+)`), then capture the group of numbers ( `([0-9]+)$` )/